# PC Kinect disconnects after 5 seco using Brekel for animation.

Tags: animation, kinect, motion, disconnect

I am trying to capture animation using a PC Kinect connected via USB 3.0  When I try to capture animation using Brekel, the PC Kinect keeps disconnecting and shutting down and only stays on for 5 seconds.  I did not have the problem before the recent Brekel update.  Anybody out there use PC Kinect and Brekel to capture animation to make animation videos?  Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I kept trying every thing for days, and finally the issue turned to be from the kinect AC adaptor...

[Kinect for Xbox 360 freezes and disconnects from USB after running Processing SimpleOpenNi depth image example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359425/kinect-for-xbox-360-freezes-and-disconnects-from-usb-after-running-processing-si/29441146#29441146)